# Using preg_match in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have string as shown below and would like to retrieve "sample text" from it using PHP. Can someone help? Can it be done using preg_match?
** [[sample text]]

Comment: [Have you tried anything?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: please post more information. The sample text and the string you with to find

Comment: Are you trying to see if the string matches, extract the string matched, replace the match, etc.?

Comment: its the same as Sumoanand described below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$text = '[This] is a [[test]] string.';
preg_match("/\[\[.*?\]\]/",$text,$matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

If there are multiple patterns:

```
$text = '[This] is a [[test]] [[string]].';
preg_match_all("/\[\[.*?\]\]/",$text,$matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Live execution: [eval.in](http://eval.in/32272)

Probably, you need this too for future reference for such problems: http://webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php

Answer (score 0):

If its always the first and last two chars you want to strip, just use substring for that. 
Or make a replace...
Check this out:
http://php.net/manual/de/function.substr-replace.php